# Make a mention use in the modal

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

I'm trying to mention a user in a modal with nextcord.py, but I can't seem to find a way.

I tried using

```
self.reported_user = nextcord.ui.TextInput(
            label=nextcord.Member,
            min_length=1,
            max_length=500,
            placeholder="Mention the user you are reporting"
        )
```

and tried doing

```
self.reported_user = nextcord.ui.TextInput(
            label=nextcord.Member.mention,
            min_length=1,
            max_length=500,
            placeholder="Mention the user you are reporting"
        )
```

but I got numerous errors, and the modal did not load.